# Getting no response from ajax searching with laravel

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel-5

I have a problem with ajax searching in my project.

This is my view:

```
<div class="col-md-12">
            {!! Form::open(['class' => 'form-horinzontal']) !!}
            {!! Form::text('search', null, array('id' => 'search-input','required','class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>'Product zoeken, begin met typen...','onkeyup' => 'search_data(this.value, "result")', 'autofocus')) !!}
            {!! Form::close() !!}
            <br>
            <script>
                function search_data(search_value) {

                    console.log(search_value);
                    $.ajaxSetup({
                        headers: {
                            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': '{{ csrf_token() }}'
                        }
                    });
                    $.ajax({
                        type : 'get',
                        url : '{{ URL::to('/webshop/products/searchProduct') }}',
                        data : {'search':search_value},
                        success:function(data) {
                            console.log(data);
                        }
                    });
                }
            </script>
        </div>
```

the Controller:

```
public function searchProduct(Request $request){

    if($request->ajax()) {
        $output = "";
        $products = Product::where('beschrijving', 'LIKE','%'. $request['search'] .'%')->get();

        if(count($products)) {
            foreach($products as $product){
                $output .= '<tr>' .
                           '<td>' . $product->beschrijving . '</td>' .
                           '<td>' . $product->artikelcode . '</td>' .
                           '<td>' . $product->prijs . '</td>' .
                           '</tr>';
            }
            return response($output);
        } else {
            return response('TESTING!');
        }
    }
}
```

and the route:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => '/webshop/products'], function() {
        Route::get('/searchProduct', 'ProductsController@searchProduct');
    });
```

i get a completely blank response, which is weird.

I also tried returning strings instead of the $ouput variable, the controller returns nothing at all.

Im getting no errors either, and i'm out of options.
The response im getting:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

My route was wrong:

Had to remove the get from the prefix group, then it worked.